# Is there a limit to how long an actor method can execute for?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I see ReplicaChangeRoleToPrimary messages when my actor is executing one its longer running methods. This Role change seems to happen after about 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The default operation timeout is 5 minutes according to `FabricTransportSettings.DefaultOperationTimeout`.

I suspect your `ActorService` is crashing, but more details about the problem would be helpful.